# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXIT and unable to use login session across pages in php

Tags: php, mysql

Getting error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXIT in C:\wamp\www\login.php on line 47. Need some help. It was working yesterday

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($email));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($password));

// Check occurence of email password combination
$sql="SELECT * FROM register WHERE email='$email'";
$result=mysql_query($sql); 


// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $email, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($password == $row['password'])
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = "1";
header("location:home.html");
exit;
}
else 
{
echo "Please enter correct Password";
header("location:login.html");
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = '' 
exit();
}
 }  
else
{
header("Location:register.html");
exit();
}

?>
```

Also added following Snippet to home.php but cant use login session

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("config.php");

if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {

header ("Location: login.html");

exit;

}
?>
```

Comment: Might be `$_SESSION['login'] = ''`. (edit)... it "IS" that line. As stated by Marc below, missing `;`.

Comment: Is this an include? You have a closing php tag but not an opening one.

Comment: Not your primary problem but you cant use header('something') after echo('something') (except if output buffering is on).

Comment: Another thing, you didn't declare `session_start();` in your top code. Must reside in all pages using the same session.

Answer (score 6):

You forgot a `;`:

```
echo "Please enter correct Password";
header("location:login.html");
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = ''    // <----here
exit();
```

This could not possibly have been working yesterday, so something's changed this script...